# How do I exclude certain components from the DevOps pipeline to push ADF to production?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, cicd

How do I exclude certain components such as triggers (in Dev environment) from the DevOps pipeline to push ADF to production?

I have come across two solutions:

1. Including a script to enable/disable triggers in YAML itself
2. .gitignore/ exclude? (not quite sure about this)

Answer (score 0):

The ARM templates are generated in `adf_publish` branch or can also be generated from your `collaboration` branch using

```
Build:
    Type: "NPM"
    PackageManager: "YARN"
    NodeVersion: "14.x"
    WorkingDirectory: "adf"
    OutputDirectory: "/adf/ArmTemplate"
    BuildCommand: 'run build export $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/adf /subscriptions/**/resourceGroups/**/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/** "ArmTemplate"'
```

Custom parameters can be defined in `arm-template-parameters-definition.json`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-resource-manager-custom-parameters

A couple of plugins that can be used to achieve CI/CD for ADF:

1. AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-resource-manager-template-deployment-v3?view=azure-pipelines
2. SQLPLayer.DataFactoryTools https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SQLPlayer.DataFactoryTools

AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment : Custom parameters can be overridden in the pipeline yaml for each env but cant be done for triggers.

DataFactoryTools: This deploys the factory jsons , there is an option to `StartStopTriggers`

A very hacky way for both above approaches is to use a `Powershell@2` task in your azdo pipeline and override the triggers each env.

```
  - task: Powershell@2
    inputs:
      script: |
        ((Get-content -path triggers/{your_trigger.json} -Raw) -replace 'old','new') | Set-Content -path triggers/{your_trigger.json}
```

So if u use `SQLPlayer.DataFactoryTools` then u can keep triggers stopped in certain envs and started in certain envs, also using the powershell plugin u can have different triggers in different envs.

Hope it helps!